# pandoc docx: no tables or bad tables

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I am trying to produce tables in docx with pandoc, but can't make it work.
LibreOffice at least tries to produce a table, while OpenOffice just ignores 
the table completely treating cells as paragraphs with alignment.

Should it work? Can I fix something in the setup to make it work? May be something can be made in styles in a reference docx?

This is the complete `tmp.md` file with three table examples:

```
plain text

  Right     Left     Center     Default
-------     ------ ----------   -------
     12     12        12            12
    123     123       123          123
      1     1          1             1


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item                        Kilowatts        Use               Cost
---------------             ---------------  ----------------  -----------
Geothermal Plant            **`1250.0`**     Electricity       **` 4.4`**

Houses                      **`13.7`**       Shelter           **` 4.2`**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


| head1 | head 2 |
|-------|---------
| data1 | data2  |
| data3 | data4  |
```

This is what I run

```
$ pandoc tmp.md -o tmp.docx
```

This is what I get in OpenOffice

[image]

This is what I get in LibreOffice
[image]

This is my pandoc version:

```
$ pandoc --version
pandoc 2.7.3
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.2, skylighting 0.8.1
```

The System is `macOS Mojave 10.14.6`

The set of table extensions is

```
$ pandoc --list-extensions| grep -i table
+grid_tables
+multiline_tables
+pipe_tables
+simple_tables
+table_captions
```

Comment: In my experience both LibreOffice and OpenOffice have terrible support for MS Word tables. The problem may not be with Pandoc at all. If you don't have a copy of MS Word to test with, then perhaps try outputting HTML to confirm that Pandoc is properly parsing your Markdown tables.

Comment: @Waylan, ah, yeah. At least I will be able to debug.

Comment: pandoc can also output to OpenOffice text document: `pandoc tmp.md -o tmp.odt`

Comment: Well yes, that seems to be a viable workaround: emit odt. Then manually convert to docx at the end of the process.